# autoupdate of an application on non rooted device in android

Tags: android, auto-update

My question is.. Is it possible to silently auto update an application on a non rooted device?
if the device is rooted then it updates my application with super user permission otherwise not.
plz do rply
thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to silently auto update an application on a non-rooted device. Android security model prevents this (for a good reason), and AFAIR there's no workaround except rooting the phone. You may check the [autoupdater source code](http://code.google.com/p/auto-update-apk-client/) I wrote to see how it's done.

Comment: u mean if i want to auto update the app first i have to root the device?

Comment: when using AutoUpdateAPK you have two choices: 1) display notification to your user and let him/her click on the notification to update, and 2) root the device and don't bother user with notifications. Personally I prefer notifications -- this is more user-friendly and non-rooted devices are considerably more stable/safer. If you strive to avoid any user interaction during the update process, the only option is to root.

Comment: Actually i want that when user clicks on update button the updated version of app gets downloaded and installed. But in my app the version get downloaded and it says application not installed.

Comment: can you show the source code where you start the installation, please?

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
             intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "MyApp.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
             startActivity(intent);

Comment: source looks fine, can you also show the logcat at the moment when installation fails? please, copy/paste in original question, because logcat is too big to fit in comment box, or use pastebin.com

Comment: there is no error in logcat. But now my application is installed. Actually my error was that i am installing from download folder when the updated file is in sdcard.

Answer (score 0):

i think i don't get your question by 100%, but have you seen the "auto update this app" on the play store?

when you download an app you have this checkbox so the user can decide. As a developer I think you cannot.