# Auto-update of Android app, without asking a user

Tags: android, auto-update

Good day,

How it's possible to perform auto-update of Android app, without asking a user?

App is not in Google Play.

Best regards.

Comment: It's not possible, unless the phone is rooted and/or you're running a signed system app.

Comment: в прошлом году я отвечал на подобный вопрос: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13118943 и с тех пор ничего не изменилось =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot silently install applications on an unrooted Stock Android device for security reasons. It is even clearly stated by Dianne (a Google Employee) [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/B7zKbvySHkU/Z3dSi3edD6AJ).

Answer (score 2):

FYI, i just read about this at 
http://blog.vivekpanyam.com/evolve-seamlessly-deploy-android-apps-to-users/?hn

> Evolve is a library for Android Developers that lets them deploy new
>   versions of an app without going through Google Play or asking users
>   to download an update. It works by using reflection and dynamic
>   bytecode generation to "trick" Android into running new code.

Also, the solution at [Update an Android app (without Google Play)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213211/update-an-android-app-without-google-play) seems to allow updating Apps without a Play store.

Comment: Seems like interesting thing. Thanks!