# How to allow application To be installed directly from website[I.E non market Application]

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, purchase-order

I have requirement like this.I have an application which needs to be published on google play store.That is a paid application.Now It's fine to publish application on play store with paid version.But my query is that,how can I allow user to purchase application directly from my website also.I.E user should be clicking on application icon and after that he/she has to purchase that application.What mechanism i have to follow for implementing such functionality for allowing user to purchase application directly from website.

Comment: You can give the link to the play store application so user will redirect to the application.
Otherwise you have to use the PayPal type of APIs and redirect the user to payment page on click on the application icon and when user paid you then provide his/her the download link to download the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to sell your app from market create your own mechanism to sell app from your website and updates of that perticular app also you have do it from in app itself, For update flow the link

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213211/update-an-android-app-without-google-play)

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup an e-commerce website and if you will need so have an ssl secured website for the same. After setting this up, you need a database to track customers and after crossing this point, here comes the surprise. User will prefer play store over any other third party website because it's been that way from the birth of Android. The time and energy spent for setting up this website will not be able to reap the benefits.

Have a website and redirect the user from your website to google play store. This is what all the major free and paid app developers are doing currently.