# Update an Android app That Is Not In Google Play

Tags: android-studio

Hello i want to insert an "service" in my android project that allows users to update the app evry time that i relase a new update(sorry if i can't explain well but english its not my language and i have some limit using it) basic i just want a way that users can update my app evry time that i relase a new one directlly from my app.I have searched on google but no sucsess and i have not tryed anything.

I Have Read This Post But I Don't Understand It Because I'am a beginner In Android Developing [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213211/update-an-android-app-without-google-play)

Comment: You cant sent a push notification with the link of your new apk.

Comment: Device updates are not from the google play store. Like that, you can use a server connection to check update for your app. Retrieve your app's version and compare with the hosted app. If newer version available then manually download it. You've to enable the option "install from unknown sources'

Comment: and how can i do it please help me i really need this... I'am a beginner in android developing so if you can please explain it well

Answer (score 0):

If you're still having this  problem, just use Google [in-app updates](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates). It's very easy and straightforward; no need for a service.