# How to check from a web if the versionName of apk with the installed apk at device it is the same or not in Android Studio

Tags: android, jsoup, androidhttpclient

I am trying to check at runtime if there is a new version of the app from an url.
I have deployed the app at the online domain which is something like this `www.test.com/androidapp/app_debug.apk` and this automatically downloads my app.
What I am trying to do is check in this link if the `versionName` of this apk it is the same with the installed one if not then I will show a `Dialog` which will give me a message with the new `versionName` and will have two buttons `Cancel && Update`.
I know how to do the `Dialog` but I don't know how to achieve this communication between the `Url` and my apk.

I have tried some code from an answer from `SO` but till now not what I am excepting for.
This is the link what I have tried.

[Answer from another question SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15213350/9560126)

Here is what I tried so far depends from the answer of @BryanIbrahim

Here I get the current version of the app.

```
String getVersionFromUrl = "http://test.com/AndroidApp/text.txt";
//At text.txt I have only test.v1.0.2

 URL u = null;

        try {
            u = new URL(path);
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.connect();
            InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
            final ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            in.read(buffer); // Read from Buffer.
            bo.write(buffer); // Write Into Buffer.
            String getVersion = bo.toString().substring(12, 17);
            String getVersionFromUrl = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
            if (!getVersionFromUrl.equals(getVersion))  {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                        builder1.setMessage("It is a new version of this app");
                        builder1.setCancelable(true);
                        builder1.setPositiveButton(
                                "Yes",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });

                        builder1.setNegativeButton(
                                "No",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });

                        builder1.show();

                    }
                });

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("YourApp", "Well that didn't work out so well...");
            Log.e("YourApp", e.getMessage());

        }
        return path;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String path) {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        String path2 = "http://test.com/AndroidApp/testv1.0.2.apk";
        i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(path2)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive" );
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       // mContext.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

At the method `onResume()` I call something like this.

```
getVersionName gTV = new getVersionName(getApplicationContext());
gTV.execute();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jsoup is not for the purpose you are using.
Better you upload a json file to your server and get it using `okhttp`.
*Example:www.oye.com/update.json*
Where you may set information for version,What's new,URL,and other info.
Otherwise you will have a bad experience using jsoup for checking your app update

**Answer Updated**
JsonFile on your server (Example:www.oye.com/update.json)

```
{   "name":"AppName",   "size":"8mb",   "url":"https://www.youall.com/update.apk",  "version":"1.08" }
```

**Using okhttp**

```
OkHttpClient client=new OkHttpClient();


Request request=new Request.Builder().url("www.oye.com/update.json").build();

        Call call = client.newCall(request);
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
                public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) 
                throws IOException
                {

JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(reponse.body().string);
                         if(obj.getDouble("version")>yourAppvrrsion){
                             //update avialable
                         }else{
                             //not avialable
                         }


}});
```

Comment: I have created there a `txt` file which I have writed something like `v1.0.2` and then I am reading it with `HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
                c.setRequestMethod("GET");
                c.connect();
                InputStream in = c.getInputStream();`
Till now it checks which version is there but the problem it is now I do not know how to update the apk from url.

Comment: Is your app available at play/app store

Comment: Nope, I am trying at first some bugs to fix and to see if the update it is possible from the Web and then I will upload to the playstore.

Comment: I have updated the question please see for changes.

Comment: How to make that update available to be installed ?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the latest version name of your app on the domain, e.g 1.0.0, instead of simply uploading the whole apk. Then using `PackageManager` retrieve the versionName and compare it with the online version.

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    try {
        PackageInfo packageInfo = packageManager.getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
        String localVersionName = packageInfo.versionName;

       //Compare with the online version
      if(localVersionName  != onlineVersionName){
       //Update the app
       }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: How to get from the domain the `versionName` how it is that possible? 
You have only added how to get the `localVersionName` ?

Comment: It would be more convenient if you had a database to set and retrieve. You could use https://jsoup.org/, a java HTML parser to extract the exact version name from an element

Comment: I am going to try that with `jsoup.org` and you said it would be more convenient if I had a database to set and retrieve what do you mean exactly ?