# Android app feature update on-demand from my own server

Tags: android, updates, store, modularity

I know that I can let users download apks from my server but...
What I need is a technique to implement a modular app with features that I can add and remove such as the Play Feature Delivery from Android App Bundles.

At the same time I can't use Google Play Store.

I read that:["App Bundle format is open source, so other stores can adopt it"](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/faq#is_the_aab_a_proprietary_format_that_can_only_be_used_on_google_play)

So I think I could implement my own store but how can I implement the Play Feature Delivery?

I read also about:

- apk split
- apk Expansion Files
- over-the-air programming
- native app over HTTP

Do you have any idea where I can start?

#### UPDATE 1

I can't put +1 but thanks to Rediska I can elaborate the question.

With `bundletool` I can generate an APK Set archive containing APKs for all possible devices.

How do I automate the installation of new features from the client point of view?

Can I use [Play Core lib](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore) or another lib?

#### UPDATE 2

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213211/update-an-android-app-without-google-play-store-visit) I found [Evolve](https://blog.vivekpanyam.com/evolve-seamlessly-deploy-android-apps-to-users/?hn).

> Evolve is a library for Android Developers that lets them deploy new
> versions of an app without going through Google Play or asking users
> to download an update. It works by using reflection and dynamic
> bytecode generation to "trick" Android into running new code.

Now, this opens to ideas but also security risks.

Answer (score 0):

There is `bundletool` - a utility for handling .aab files. It is [open source](https://github.com/google/bundletool/releases), and it does have the ability to generate APK files based on specs.

Comment: Yes, I know that I can create apks from aab with the "build-apks" command.

But from the clients point of view, do they just need to download the apk from the remote server? 
The installation of the additional features can be automated with the Play Core Library or another library?

Comment: did you find the solution :app feature update on-demand from my own server?